# 'update-ca-certificates' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: docker, windows-10

in docker file I have code like below , trying to build code in docker

```
  FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

  ARG https_proxy
  ARG http_proxy

  ENV https_proxy $https_proxy
  ENV http_proxy $http_proxy

  EXPOSE 60717
  EXPOSE 5000
  EXPOSE 44356

  COPY tools/TestCertROOT.cer /usr/local/share/ca- certificates/TestCertROOT.crt
  RUN update-ca-certificates
```

as i do  docker-compose up, i get following output

```
 λ  docker-compose up
 Creating network "test-api_default" with the default driver
 Building api
 Step 1/22 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk
 ---> f94ae7685e49
 Step 2/22 : ARG https_proxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d20c63454ff
 Step 3/22 : ENV https_proxy $https_proxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> aba74e74813f
 Step 4/22 : ENV http_proxy $https_proxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 66c69a63f8cd
 Step 5/22 : ENV no_proxy 
 "db2,mainframe,localhost,.kaccess.net,.kaccess.com.au,.kmtltd.net.au,.compute.internal,.a- 
 **************************,git.caccess.net"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 535f6fa37c2a
 Step 6/22 : COPY tools/TestCertROOT.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/TestROOT.crt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1b25c7e4d7f1
 Step 7/22 : RUN update-ca-certificates
 ---> Running in 8c3ad5ed6117
 'update-ca-certificates' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command 'cmd /S /C update-ca-certificates' returned a non- 
 zero code: 1
```

I have installed CA certificate but still I  am getting same issue.

Comment: I guess you might have to change your base image.

Comment: how can i do that? @Technext

Comment: Try replacing `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build` with `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS build`

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: yes i did but still same issue i am getting

Comment: Ok. Replace `RUN update-ca-certificates` with `RUN /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command 'cmd /S /C /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211782/discussion-between-technext-and-ashu).

Comment: Which version of the docker cli are you using? I'm using the community edition on my dev. machine and the EE on our deploy server (Windows Server 2019). Only the latter reports the same error as you reported in the TS